# Why does a double-slit experiment with sound waves never result in complete destructive interference?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, double-slit-experiment, interference

Today, I find a question that if the speakers are set in parallel towards the wall. It has no complete destructive interference due to difference in distance from the point to each speakers, which leads difference in intensity, amplitude...(Answer is D)
[image]

However, for the young's double slit there is also difference between the point and the slits. So, there should be difference in intensity,amplitude, isn't it? However, we consider it as they are having complete destructive interference so they have no intensity, dark region, at some point.

Is it because the electromagnetic wave has high frequency, so we assume that there is no decrease in intensity, amplitude is negligible??

Comment: It is because the person who has written the question didn't think of it that way! Of course the intensity goes to zero if we assume a perfect setup.

Comment: The size of the sources relative to wavelength and distance to the 'screen' also play a role.

Comment: Given that the first speaker's coil probably induces a phase shift in the current reaching the second speaker,  I would bet that the pattern is **not** symmetric about the midpoint of line $XY$ .  The person who wrote the question was rather sloppy.  I'm guessing he wants the decaying maxima to look like the envelope of a single speaker, but why there's a nonzero floor is quite unclear.

Comment: If D is the answer they expect, the problem is poorly-worded. That's the down side of multiple choice tests.  Maybe they intend for you to consider the reflections from the other walls will prevent a complete destructive interference. That's what will happen if you do the experiment in a real classroom.

Comment: Note that there is as assumption in the elementary treatment of the two-slit experiment that the distance $l$ between the screens is *much* larger than the distance $d$ between the slits. When those conditions are met, there is negligible intensity variation between the two sources across one fringe, so you don't notice the non-zeroness of the dark fringes. In the image shown above that condition $l \gg d$ is not present and you must do a more complete analysis.

Comment: Are you describing an experiment that somebody actually performed?  Perhaps they did not control the conditions well enough.  For example, unless the experiment is performed in an absolutely anechoic chamber, then the contribution of each speaker is going to be _much_ more complicated than just a pure, spherical wave.

Answer (score 2):

The reason D is the "correct" answer, is because the key word **best**, is used.
Although any answer may not be 100% correct, if at least one of the answers is better than the others, then **that** would make it the correct answer.  A and B are eliminated because the amplitude should decrease as one moves away from the XY center line.  C is eliminated because it shows **no interference**.  D is the only one that shows both decrease in amplitude and signal interference.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the speakers are not point sources so that there is a slight spreading of each maxima so adjacent maxima overlap slightly?

Comment: To add to my comment above: the fact that  the wavelength of sound is much bigger than light means the effect is much more exaggerated for sound in the interference pattern